# Remove email address from "from" list in Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

I have tried searching for an answer for this but can't find it.

In Outlook (2010) I have multiple email accounts, but only wish to send email from one of them.

I have disabled the "Send Mail Items" checkbox in Send/Receive Groups but there are 2 issues with this.

1. Outlook still shows the email account in the list of accounts I can
   send "From" when writing a new email
2. If an email is sent from one of these "Recieve Only" email
   accounts, Outlook will not alert me of this and it will just remain
   in the outbox.

I have a few non tech-savvy users in my team and I am very concerned this will be an issue

So, my question is, how do I remove the unwanted email account from the "From" list.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

According to [Slipstick Systems](https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/outlook-2010/multiple-accounts-and-the-default-account/), you can use the registry to force Outlook to use the default account for all sent messages.

1. Navigate to
   `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\​Software\​Microsoft\​Office\​14.0\​Outlook\​Options\​Mail`
2. Add a new DWORD named **NewItemsUseDefaultSendingAccount**
3. Set its value to `1`

This will not ask for user input. It simply uses the default account any time a user selects to send a new message.